# How to programatically change text of tkinter notebook tab AFTER adding it

Tags: python, tkinter

How can I change the text of a Python 3.5 tkinter Notebook tab programatically AFTER adding it to the notebook?

So I have added a tab with:

`notebookWidget.add (tabWidget, text = 'myOldText')`

which works fine.

Now, I want to do something like:

```
tabWidget.text = 'myNewText'
```

or, (more tkinter'ish?):

```
tabWidget ['text'] = 'myNewText'
```

Comment: Which doesn't work...

Comment: @Rightleg: if you're going to give advice like that, make sure it's _good_ advice. What you suggest won't work.

Answer (score 3):

Found it:

```
notebookWidget.tab (tabWidget, text = 'myNewText')
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer is (where tab_idx is the 0 based index of the tab within the notebokk):

```
notebook_widget.tab(tab_idx, text='Another text')
```

Answer (score -3):

There is a basic method inherited from [`Widget`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ttk.html#ttk.Widget) which is called [`configure()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-widget-configuration.htm) and does the job you expect:

```
tabWidget.configure(text = 'myNewText')
```

Comment: I've just tried that, but it results in the following: _tkinter.TclError: unknown opition "-text"

Comment: You are right, text option is not listed in the documentation, sorry.

Comment: Thank you, Camille. I didn't  downvote you... Someone had a bad day it seems... (Well, of course I can correct that...)

Comment: @jacquesdehooge: I downvoted, because this answer isn't the least bit helpful. It is a _wrong_ answer, and anybody would be wrong to upvote it. If a provably incorrect answer isn't grounds for a downvote, I don't know what is.

Comment: Alright Bryan, you've got a point there. Just could imagine the confusion, because I made the same mistake...